# Handle items from multi viewController

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, swiftui, swift5

Hi im trying to build ordering food application but i faced a problem which is i want to separate the cartTableViewController for multi viewController.
i don’t know how to explain it because my english is soo bad but i will try my best to explain it … what i mean is let say that the user has been added items from burgerKingViewController to the cartTableViewController and he move on to mcdonaldsViewController to add items to the cartTableViewController ,, here i want to show an alert for the user saying that he has an items in his cart from burgerKingViewController and he should delete it so he can add items from mcdonaldsViewController

to simplify it more .. i want the cartTableViewController handle only one restaurant so i can take the order from firebase.

thanks.

this is the code i use it to add the item to the cartTableViewController

```
import UIKit

struct userData {
static var selectedItem: Item? = nil
static var selectedItems: [Item] = []



static func selectedItemsPrice() -> Double {
    var result: Double = 0
    for item in selectedItems {
        result = result + item.price
    }
    return result
 }

 static func allItemsToString() -> String {
    var allNames: [String] = []
    for item in selectedItems {
        allNames.append(item.name)
    }
    return allNames.joined(separator: ", ")
  }



  }


struct Item: Equatable {

static let items : [Item] = {
    let food: Item = .init(image: UIImage(named: “food”)!, name: “food, price: 50)
    return [food]
  }()
var image: UIImage?
var name: String
var price: Double

  }
```

this is the cartTableViewController

```
 import UIKit


 class cartTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 @IBOutlet var checkOutPressed: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet var cartView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet var totalOrder: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet var cartTableView: UITableView!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    
    checkOutPressed.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    
  }



  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    priceLabel.text = "\(userData.selectedItemsPrice())"
    totalOrder.text = "\(userData.allItemsToString())"
    
    
    
    
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

  }


  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)   -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    
    
    
    
    
    return userData.selectedItems.count
    
    
    
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    105
}







override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell") as! cartTableViewCell
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    cell.cartImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.cartImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.cartImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.cartImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.cartLabel.textColor = .black
    cell.cartLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    
    
    
    let cart = userData.selectedItems[indexPath.row]
    
   
    cell.cartImage.image = cart.image
    cell.cartLabel.text = cart.name
    cell.priceLabel1.text = “\(cart.price)"
    

    return cell


}







// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



// Override to support editing the table view.




// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
    
}



// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        
        // remove the item from the data model
        userData.selectedItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // delete the table view row
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        priceLabel.text = "\(userData.selectedItemsPrice())"
        totalOrder.text = "\(userData.allItemsToString())"
        
        
        
        
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Not used in our example, but if you were adding a new row, this is where you would do it.
        
    }
}



@IBAction func checkOutPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
    
    if priceLabel.text! == "" || totalOrder.text! == "" {
        
        // Alert
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: “please add item”, preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        // Add actions to the menu
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler:
                                            nil)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        // Display the menu
        self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}


}
```

this is burgerKingViewController

```
 import UIKit

 class burgerKingViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var burgerKingImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var burgerKingName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var burgerKingPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var makeOrder: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
super.viewDidLoad()
    
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    makeOrder.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0



  }




@IBAction func makeOrder(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: “done”, preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        // your code with delay
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    userData.selectedItems.append(Item(image: UIImage(named: “burgerKing”), name: “burgerKing”, price: Double(10.000)))
    
    
    
    
    self.aimateView(sender)
    
    
    
    
}




fileprivate func aimateView( _ viewToAnimate:UIView) {
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        
        viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.92, y: 0.92)
        
        
        
    }) { (_) in
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            
        }, completion: nil)
    }
   }






}
```

and this is mcdonaldsViewController

```
import UIKit

class mcdonaldsViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var mcdonaldsImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var mcdonaldsName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var mcdonaldsPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var makeOrder: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    
    makeOrder.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0

 }





@IBAction func makeOrder(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: “done”, preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    // change to desired number of seconds (in this case 5 seconds)
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        // your code with delay
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    
    userData.selectedItems.append(Item(image: UIImage(named: "mcdonalds"), name: "mcdonalds", price: Double(10.000)))
    
    
    
    
    self.aimateView(sender)
    
    
    
    
}




fileprivate func aimateView( _ viewToAnimate:UIView) {
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        
        viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.92, y: 0.92)
        
        
        
    }) { (_) in
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}






}
```

Comment: Too many... would you provide minimal reproducible example that depicts the problem?

Comment: @Asperi  I want the cartTableViewController handle only one restaurant items so i can take the order from firebase.